# JBoss 7 support for TLS1.1 and TLS1.2

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, tls1.2, tls1.1

I am new to the JBoss server and I need to migrate my application from JBoss 5.1 to JBoss 7.

Currently JBoss 5.1 is using `SSLProtocal=TLS` and in JBoss 7 I need to use `SSLProtocal=TLSv1.0,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2` as per the JBoss documentation.

---

Can anyone help me on following points:

- Does JBoss 7 support TLS1.0, TLS1.1, TLS1.2?
- Suppose one request is coming from a TLS 1.0 supported client and another is coming from TLS 1.2 supported client. Is there any issue anyone faced?
- I have read on some forums that sometime if the first request is coming from a TLS1.2 client and the handshake is successful, and then if any client is sending a request with TLS1.0 version, the server refused the request. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not migrate to JBoss AS 7.1, it is old and has many bugs. If you're looking for the community application server from JBoss you should migrate to WildFly AS 10.1. If you're talking about EAP, then version 7 is fine.
2. JBoss AS 7.1 does support TLS1.0, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2. See https://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20AS7/7.1.1/subsystem/web/connector/ssl/configuration/index.html
3. The TLS version of one client does not have any effect on the TLS version of an other client.